# Where to add @XMLElement(name="name") annotation

Tags: java, jersey

Where do I use @XMLElement annotation in my class?

URL:http://localhost:8080/GigstartServices/GET/Users/2/Orders

I want it to be

```
<Orders>
<Order>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

**instead of**

```
<Orderss>
<Orders>
</Orders>
</Orderss>
```

[image]

I have following classes for Orders in my project.

OrderResource.java :

```
package com.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;

import com.dto.Orders;

public class OrderResource {
int total;

    public ArrayList<Orders> GetOrders(Connection connection, int id) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<Orders> feedData = new ArrayList<Orders>();
        ArrayList<Integer> itemsId;
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT o.id , o.userId FROM dbo.Orders o join dbo.Items I on o.itemId = I.id join dbo.Users u on o.UserId = u.Id where o.userId = ? group by o.id, o.userId");
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                Orders o = new Orders();
                o.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT o.ItemId, price FROM dbo.Orders o join dbo.Items I on o.itemId = I.id WHERE o.UserId= ? and o.Id = ?");
                ps.setInt(1, rs.getInt("userId"));
                ps.setInt(2, rs.getInt("id"));
                ResultSet rs2 = ps.executeQuery();
                itemsId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                total = 0;
                while(rs2.next()){
                itemsId.add(rs2.getInt("ItemId"));
                total = total + rs2.getInt("price");

                }
                o.setItem(itemsId);
                o.setUserId(rs.getInt("userId"));
                o.setTotalAmount(total);
                feedData.add(o);
            }
            return feedData;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

2. package com.webService;

   ```
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   import javax.ws.rs.GET;
   import javax.ws.rs.Path;
   import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
   import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
   import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;

   import com.dao.Database;
   import com.dao.OrderResource;
   import com.dao.Resources;
   import com.dto.Items;
   import com.dto.Orders;
   @Path("/")  
   public class OrderService {
   OrderService(){

   }
       ArrayList<Orders> u = null;
   Database database= new Database();

       @GET
       @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
       public ArrayList<Orders> getOrders(@PathParam("userid") int userid) throws Exception
       {
           Connection connection = database.GetConnection();
           OrderResource ur= new OrderResource();
           u=ur.GetOrders(connection, userid);
        return u;
       }
   ```

   }

3.

```
 package com.dto;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Orders {

    private int id;
    private ArrayList<Integer> items;
    private int userId;
    private int totalAmount;

public Orders(){

    }
private ArrayList<Integer> Items;

    public Orders(int id,ArrayList<Integer> items, int userId , int totalAmount){
        Items = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        this.id = id;
        this.items = items;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;

    }
    /**
     * @return the Id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * set Id
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @return the ItemId
     */
    /*@XmlElementWrapper(name="Items")
    @XmlElement(name="Item")
    public ArrayList<Integer> getItemId() {
        return Items;
    }
    /**
     * @set name
     */
    /*public void setItem(ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
    */
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Items")
    @XmlElement(name="Item")
    public ArrayList<Integer> getItemId() {
        return items;
    }
    /**
     * @set name
     */
    public void setItem(ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
    /**
     * @return price
     */
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    /**
     * set price
     */
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int getTotalAmount(){
        return totalAmount;
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(int totalAmount){
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `Orders` class, add the `name` to the `@XmlRootElement`. The default will be the name of the class. So each order will be `<Orders>` and when it gets wrapped (because it's in a list) the wrapper element will simply append an `s`, which will give you `<Orderss>`. So just set the `name` to `Order`

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Order")
public class Orders
```

Or simply change the name of the class to `Order`, which to me actually makes more sense semantically, since an instance of the class is just one order, not plural (multiple orders).